# How can I alias a subdomain to an external site using DNS?

Tags: dns, linode

I have a site hosted on [Linode](http://linode.com).  I use Linode's DNS (with Apache) for things like mail, `blog.mysite.com`-type subdomains, etc.

I want to use `strikingly.com` for my main page, hosted at `www.mysite.com`.  Is there a way I can configure the DNS Manager (in Linode) to have `www.mysite.com` hosted at Strikingly while keeping `mysite.com` at Linode?

I tried adding a CNAME entry for the subdomain `www` with a target `mysite.strikingly.com`, but it doesn't seem to do anything at all (it serves my local apache on linode).  But I don't really understand DNS details like CNAME...

Comment: No, DNS is not enough.  DNS only assigns IP addresses.   You also need to configure the web server to do the correct thing when it gets a request for that domain name.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an A record in the DNS.

Say you have site linode.com at 10.0.0.1 and site strikingly.com at 10.0.0.3, the DNS entry would be something like that for `www`:

```
        A       10.0.0.1
www     A       10.0.0.3
```

Then on that server (10.0.0.3) you need to accept the `www.mysite.com` name in Apache. If that's the default website, then you're set. If that's just one of the websites, but not the default, make sure to have an entry such as:

```
<VirtualHost>
    # Handle www.mysite.com
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

With a CNAME, it will work too if you have a domain with the correct IP address. So say you define a sub domain `strikingly.mysite.com` and set that to the strikingly IP address:

```
strikingly   A     10.0.0.3
www          CNAME strikingly
```

The good thing with using a CNAME is that if the IP changes, you can change it in one location and all the other references get changed automatically. It's like having a DNS variable...